# Is there a flavour of libreoffice that is better looking

Tags: libreoffice, appearance

I have set up ubuntu at my office and one thing I hear no end is how ugly libreoffice is. Is there a flavour of libreoffice that looks better??? My colleagues are use to office so when they go to libreoffice the first thing they say is that it is ugly :-( - looks are a barrier for some people!

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have `libreoffice-gtk` package installed.
With this package, *libreoffice* is better integrated aesthetically in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

IBM's Lotus Symphony is aesthetically (and only in that way) better , in my opinion at least. It is based on openoffice - the suite libreoffice is based on as well. A previous version of it though, if i remember correctly.

Libreoffice with libreoffice-gtk installed is nicer than the one without it as well (or -qt, if you are not on gnome)